# How long does bank verification take with PayPal?

Tags: paypal

I have created a business account on PayPal. I wanted to add a bank account, so I navigated to *My Account* → *Profile* → **Add or Remove Bank Account** and I entered my IBAN number. In order to activate my PayPal account, I get a deposit from them and I need to enter the deposit amount. I get all deposits via post. But I have waited 8 days and still haven't received a deposit.

How long does this take normally? Should I contact PayPal?

Comment: So it took about a month.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-My-Account/Verification-delay/td-p/699267) has:

> Can take several days ... if nothing after 5, suggest contacting customer support direct for assistance.

which seems reasonable to me.